# Jekyll make url clickable

Tags: url, markdown, jekyll

Is it possible to make `https://stackoverflow.com/` clickable without using markdown syntax `[https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/)`? It is rendered as text by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it will depend on the [markdown interpreter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/) you use but on a default installation of Jekyll, you should get this result by using `<` and `>` around your URL.

```
<https://stackoverflow.com/>
```

I found this info in this cheat sheet, which you might find useful too : [Markdown Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#links)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, [kramdown link](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#links-and-images) doesn't support pure url.